# Do open and close votes age away after a few days?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work)

I have noticed that, on some questions with a single close vote, I have come back later to check and the vote is gone.

Is that because the votes "age away" after 2 days (like flags) if the five vote threshold is not met, or do the moderators periodically sweep old questions with lingering close and open votes?  Does it work the same way for reopen votes as well?

Comment: Yes. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work/10583#10583 ("Votes to close and reopen expire after 4 days")

Comment: I appreciate the community's diligence in closing this as a duplicate, but the information is buried in the middle of an answer on the other question, and even with the link, it took me a minute to find it. Questions are supposed to be closed because they are *exact duplicates;* questions that do get closed seldom get merged, they just get deleted. Sorry for stepping on the soapbox, but IMO closing near-duplicates is by far the most abused aspect of SO.

Comment: the problem comes when information contained in a FAQ *changes*... Sooner or later, someone will probably edit the "closed questions FAQ", but now someone will need to edit this one as well. I'm sorry you had trouble finding the answer in the existing FAQ, but perhaps you could find a way to improve the language or layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Votes expire after 4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-how-do-they-work/10583#10583) AND moderators will sometimes clear them.